# How do they come up with this Maximum a Posteriori probability here?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, solution-verification, bayesian

For the following problem, it is said that:

`...the MAP estimate is equal to x.`

Where does that come from?  Is it because of the special case of one single prior distribution, and there is only one possibility?

[image: map]

Comment: Because probability of $\theta$ decreases with increasing value, and its maximum is when $\theta = x$. Because $x \leq \theta \leq 1$.

Comment: Oh I see it now.  Thank you so much!!!